# javascript / d3 - images in tooltip

Tags: d3.js

How would I change this code to plot images in a d3 tooltip?

```
    var tip = d3.tip() 
    .attr('class', 'd3heatmap-tip')
    .html(function(d, i) {
      return "<table>" + 
        "<tr><th align=\"right\">Row</th><td>" + htmlEscape(data.rows[d.row]) + "</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><th align=\"right\">Column</th><td>" + htmlEscape(data.cols[d.col]) + "</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><th align=\"right\">Value</th><td>" + htmlEscape(d.label) + "</td></tr>" +
        "</table>";
    })
    .direction("se")
.style("position", "fixed");
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure what constitute a reproducible example in this case...

Comment: Use an img tag rather than a table I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using foxToolTip.js.  There's an example of how to use images inside a tooltip, as well as how to use with d3.

https://github.com/MichaelRFox/foxToolTip.js